# Very Low training speed of my Tensorflow model using python3.5

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am training a Seq2seq-like model using tf=1.4.0 and python=3.5.2. when training, I found the training speed is very slow: At first, it was about **1.5 min / 20 iteration**, then after some iteration, it decreased to about **4-5min / 20 iteration**. Then sometimes the speed is 1.5min, sometime is 4-5min. 
Thus, the GPU utility is very low, because most time the GPU utility is 0%.

I want to know why, and how to prevent this.

I guess this have a lot to do with a float **ndarray with shape=[batch=16, max_len about 500, 30000], about 900MB**, and this array caused gc frequently. Am I right? and how to overcome this?

Thanks in advance!

[this is my training log on github](https://github.com/huosan0123/seq2seq/blob/master/181203.log)

[image: traing CPU & Mem state]

Comment: Idk if you are right or wrong nobody can tell much with the information here, Some general advice: Make sure you don't create new tensors in a loop. If you are reading the data from disk for every step, try to store all of the data in RAM (if you have enough RAM). Post the code

Comment: thx. I will post my whole model in github. I have already load data into RAM, then process it into a batch. I don't create new tensors in a loop.

Comment: my code has already uploaded to github

Comment: sorry, didn't notice